# How to set content for template in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

From the below code not able to get the id for template. Trying to set content for template using id. But not working. How to do in JavaScript.

HTML:

```
 <template id="management" is="dom-if" if="[[flag]]"> </template>
```

JavaScript:

```
var flag = true;
const appDiv = document.getElementById('management');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Power management</h1>`;
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/anagram-implementation-nimzfz?file=index.html,index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots) are to be used. You get the template content and THEN manipulate the content and then insert the (cloned) manipulated content into the page DOM

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById('management').content;
appDiv.querySelector("h1").textContent = `Power management`;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(appDiv)
```

```html
<template id="management">
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
</template>
```